# Facebook Like link to files

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't find a way how to like link to a file ? Is it even possible ?
Example:

```
https://example.com/somefile.jpg/zip
```

And i would like to share that link to, so title description etc. is very desirable but I don't know where to put tags for og:url etc. since there are no meta tags at this.

Comment: Share an HTML document instead, that returns the meta data, and triggers the actual file download via meta refresh or JavaScript. Or make your server return an HTML document _instead_ of the file, when the requesting user-agent is the Facebook scraper.

Comment: You helped me a lot today :) Thnx. Make this as answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not directly possible; we can of course not put HTML meta elements into jpeg or zip file.

But you can try and tackle this either of those two ways:

- Share an HTML document instead, that returns the meta data, and triggers the actual file download via meta refresh or JavaScript. Or,
- make your server return an HTML document *instead* of the file, only when the requesting User-Agent is the Facebook scraper.